What points to Jesus in the Pentateuch?
A few years ago I came upon an idea that different things/persons points to Jesus in the Pentateuch. For example,

in Genesis → Joseph;
in Exodus → the Passover lamb;
in Leviticus → goat for Azazel;
in Numbers → not sure what was here;
in Deuteronomy → not sure here too.

Note that I might be wrong about what I've heard theologically or even literally. I don't have any theological studies.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  Please take our Tour to see how we are different to other sites and tips to help you ask questions: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

This kind of question isn't suitable for this site (See Help Center for what is acceptable.) ¶ Meanwhile, you might do some searches for "messianic prophecy" on the web in general and on the companion Christianity Stack Exchange site.

@Hreceniuc - What if you narrowed your question down to, ""How does the book of Hebrews point to Jesus as the  the main topic of the Pentateuch? "  This would keep your question from being overly-broad, and then suitable for this site. The book of Hebrews points to Jesus on many fronts.

This question is about to be closed because it is simply looking for a text.  However, in the spirit of helpfulness, let me provide some references.
Let me be very open - I believe every page of Scripture teaches about Jesus.  In the Pentateuch we have the following small sample from the HUGE amount of material available:

Prophecies of Messiah in the Pentateuch

One normally lists the following prophecies found in the Pentateuch:

Gen 3:15 - Jesus was the promised seed of the woman, Gal 3:16
Gen 49:10 - Jesus was the promised king who inherited the throne of david, Luke 1:31-35
Num 24:17 - Jesus was the star, Matt 2:2
Deut 18:15, 18-20 - Jesus was the promised prophet to come, Acts 3:21-23


The Israelite Ceremonial System - the "Lamb of God"

The New Testament makes much use of Sanctuary imagery in at least five different ways:

As a teaching device of Jesus and the plan of salvation (as in the Old Testament).  See “Theodicy”.  Specifically, many of the elements of the sanctuary are explained.


The sacrificial lamb represented Jesus (John 1:29, Rom 8:3, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19, Heb 9:12)
Jesus’ teaching is closely associated with water (in the laver), John 4:13, 14.
Jesus was the bread of life as symbolized by the shew bread (John 6:35-51)
The light of the Menorah represented Jesus (John 8:12, 9:5)
Jesus was the door (John 10:7-9)
Jesus opened the curtain to the Most Holy Place (2 Cor 3:13-16, Heb 6:19, 9:3, 10:20)
The smoke from the altar of incense represents the prayers of the saints (Rev 5:8, 8:3, 4)
The Ark of the covenant, especially the “mercy seat” represented the throne of God and its implied mercy (Ex 25:17-22, Heb 9:5, 4:16, Rom 3:23-25)
Jesus is represented as our great High Priest and intercessor in heaven (Heb 4:16, 7:25, 10:22, Rom 8:26, 34, 1 John 2:1, 2, 1 Tim 2:5, John 14:6)


The Temple represented Jesus’ body (John 2:19-21)

The Temple represented a Christian’s body (1 Cor 6:19, 20).  See “Health”.

The Temple represents the community of believers (or church) (1 Cor 3:16, 17, 2 Cor 6:16, Eph 2:19-22)

The earthly temple represented the heavenly temple (Heb 8:2, 9:11).  This is not to suggest that the heavenly temple is anything physically like the earthly one – far from it (the heavenly temple does not have an altar of burnt offering, nor does it have embroidered angels on the curtains, it is inconceivable that it is constructed of dyed rams' skin and beavers' hides, etc).  The Heavenly temple is nowhere described and is vastly grander and beyond description.  However, the earthly temple/tabernacle represented the work of Jesus and His mediatorial work of intercession as our Great High priest in Heaven (Heb 4:16, 7:25, 10:22, Rom 8:26, 34, 1 John 2:1, 2, 1 Tim 2:5, John 14:6) as shown above.

Jesus re-lived the OT history





OT History
Jesus’ Life




The progeny of Abraham that created the nation of Israel was made possible by miraculous births of Isaac & Jacob (=Israel)
Jesus’ earthly life became possible by the miraculous birth facilitated by the Holy Spirit


Israel is called God’s first-born son, Ex 4:22
Jesus is Mary’s first-born son, Matt 1:25


Jacob’s family left Canaan for Egypt to escape death by famine
Jesus’ family left Canaan for Egypt to escape death decree by Herod


Israel called out of Israel to become God’s people
Jesus; family called out of Egypt to become God’s chosen Messiah


Israel passes through the Red Sea equivalent to a “baptism” 1 Cor 10:2
Jesus baptized at the beginning of His ministry


After passing through the Red Sea, Israel follows the cloud into the desert
After His baptism, Jesus is led by the Spirit into the desert, Matt 4:1


Israel roamed for 40 years in the desert
Jesus spent 40 days fasting in the desert


When in the desert, Israel becomes hungry
Jesus fasted in the desert and was hungry


Israel healed and saved by faith when they looked at the uplifted bronze serpent
Jesus is the uplifted bronze serpent that saves by faith, John 3:14, 15


Israel fed by “bread from heaven” Jesus is the bread from heaven, John 6



Israel saved by the water from the rock
Jesus is the rock, 1 Cor 10:3, 4 and is the water of life, John 4:10-14, 7:37-39


Moses climbed the mountain to get the law of God
Jesus delivered his sermon of the mount (Matt 5-7) expanding the law


The whole ceremonial system represented Jesus as typified by the sacrificial lamb
Jesus is the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world, John 1:29


The Israelites were led by a divine light, the pillar of fire Jesus is the light of the world, John 8:12, 9:4, 5



Israel began its national history with 12 tribes
Jesus began His kingdom with 12 chosen disciples


God used many miracles to establish the Israelite faith
Jesus used many miracles to establish the faith of disciples and Christians


King David captured Jerusalem and it became, “The City of David”.
Jesus “captured” Jerusalem at His triumphal entry as king is Israel, John 12:12-15.


God establishes a covenant with Israel in Ex 19-23
Jesus established (or re-established) the (new) covenant


Israel was taken captive from the promised land and Jerusalem for their sins
Jesus was taken captive in Jerusalem for the sins of the world and taken outside the city to be crucified


The Jews were miraculously preserved and returned to Jerusalem after the Babylonian captivity
Jesus was miraculously resurrected from the dead and returned to Jerusalem to meet the disciples




Thank you very much for your answer! You provided a lot of great ideas.

Sorry for the question being off-topic and thanks for answering despite the fact you could only close it. Really appreciate!
